# How to center a text vertically in a narrow textview in Android?

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` which has a `height` of 30px and a `textsize` of 40px. Since the text is taller than the `View`, I only want to display the middle part of the text.Like this:[image]

But with `android:gravity="center_vertical"`, I only can display the upper part of the text with some bottom part cut off.[image]

And this is my code:

```
 <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="30px"
         android:textSize="40px"
         android:text="ABCDEFG" 
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
         />
```

Anyone knows of any way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Post your code, with layout image

Comment: Here comes the xml element
         <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="30px"
         android:textSize="40px"
         android:text="ABCDEFG" 
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
         />
       And That's all。

Answer (score 2):

Can't you simply wrap it in a LinearView set to the appropriate size and adjust the margin within the textview to about half (depending on padding) the font size?

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Sliced in half"
        android:textSize="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Resulting in:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEdxx.png

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt whether you can do that. All the options that I have come across while dealing with `TextView` are for when the Text is smaller than the View. This is the first question that I have come across which has the requirement otherwise. 
One option which I had used before was `android:scrollHorizontally="true"` where in you specify whether the text is allowed to be wider than the View.

Interesting question. It would be great if you could add some code though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,In fact this is not actually useful in my project,But I am just curious...